# Importance of a Random Variable using Entropy or other method

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

I have a two-dimensional random vector $\mathbf{x} = [x_1, x_2]^T$ with a known joint probability density function (pdf). The pdf is non-Gaussian and the two entries of the random vector are statistically *dependent*. I need to show that for example $x_1$ is *more important* than $x_2$, in terms of the amount of *information* that it carries. Is there a classical solution for this problem? Can I show that for example n% of the *total information* carried by $\mathbf{x}$ is in $x_1$ and 100-n% is carried by $x_2$?

I assume that the standard way of measuring the amount of *information* is by calculating the Entropy. Any clues?

Comment: Information about what? This only makes sense when there is a third random variable or some similar setup since mutual information is symmetric. That is $I(X_1;X_2)=I(X_2;X_3)$.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to "measure the (average) information" of a random variable is just to compute its entropy. By that reasoning, you  would say that $X_1$ gives more information than $X_2$ if $H(X_1)>H(X_2)$.  Note that, for this, the fact that the variables are or not independent, is irrelevant.

**However**, that makes sense only for discrete variables. For continuous variables, the entropy is infinite - and the "[differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Extending_discrete_entropy_to_the_continuous_case)", though generally finite, is not a very useful measure of information content - for one thing, it depends on the scale.

> Can I show that for example n% of the *total information* carried by $\mathbf{x}$ is in $x_1$ and 100-n% is carried by $x_2$?

The "total (joint) information" is $H(X_1,X_2) = H(X_1)+H(X_2)-I(X_1;X_2)$
Hence it's hard to make sense of such a division.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. Let me express the entire problem: A sunusoidal signal with a known frequency and amplitude is diluted by additive zero-mean Gaussian noise of known variance. We convert the signal into its analytical form using narrowband filtering and the Hilbert transform. The noted vector $\mathbf{x}= [x_1, x_2]^T$ contains the random variables corresponding to the magnitude and phase of the analytical form (with calculated calculated PDFs). Now want to check which of the two parameters (magnitude and phase) convey more information regarding $\mathbf{x}$ and the original signal.

Comment: By the way, the application is such that I'm only interested in the signal distribution as a random variable. Therefore, I'm not looking at the temporal characteristics due to the Hilbert transform filtering. That's why I dropped the time index $t$.

Comment: I'm currently looking at KL-Divergence as a potential measure. For instance, by calculating something like $D_{KL}(\mathbf{x}||x_1)$ versus $D_{KL}(\mathbf{x}||x_2)$. Does that make any sense? If we could for example show that $D_{KL}(\mathbf{x}||x_1) > D_{KL}(\mathbf{x}||x_2)$, would that prove anything?